# how to retrieve facebook user name and notifications in android?

Tags: java, android, facebook

Hello I neeed to retrieve User Name and notifications from a facebook profile, this is my facebook conector code:

```
import com.FeedPass.SessionEvents.AuthListener;
import com.FeedPass.SessionEvents.LogoutListener;

public class FacebookConnector {
private Facebook facebook = null;
private Context context;
private String[] permissions;
private Handler mHandler;
private Activity activity;
private SessionListener mSessionListener = new SessionListener();
private String _accessToken;

public FacebookConnector(String appId,Activity activity,Context context,String[] permissions){
    this.facebook = new Facebook(appId);

    SessionStore.restore(facebook, context);

    SessionEvents.addAuthListener(mSessionListener);
    SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(mSessionListener);
    this.context=context;
    this.permissions=permissions;
    this.mHandler = new Handler();
    this.activity=activity;
}

public void login() {
    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this.activity, this.permissions,new LoginDialogListener());
    }
}

public void logout() {
    SessionEvents.onLogoutBegin();
    AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(this.facebook);
    asyncRunner.logout(this.context, new LogoutRequestListener());
}

public void postMessageOnWall(String msg) {
    if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", msg);
        try {
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        login();
    }
}   

public String getNotifications(){
    String result = null;
    if(facebook.isSessionValid()){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, _accessToken);
        try{
            result = facebook.request("me/notifications", bundle, "GET");
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        login();
    }
    return result;
}

private final class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        SessionEvents.onLoginSuccess();
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        SessionEvents.onLoginError(error.getMessage());
    }

    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        SessionEvents.onLoginError(error.getMessage());
    }

    public void onCancel() {
        SessionEvents.onLoginError("Action Canceled");
    }
}

public class LogoutRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {
    public void onComplete(String response, final Object state) {
        // callback should be run in the original thread, 
        // not the background thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                SessionEvents.onLogoutFinish();
            }
        });
    }
}

private class SessionListener implements AuthListener, LogoutListener {

    public void onAuthSucceed() {
        SessionStore.save(facebook, context);
    }

    public void onAuthFail(String error) {
    }

    public void onLogoutBegin() {           
    }

    public void onLogoutFinish() {
        SessionStore.clear(context);
    }
}

public Facebook getFacebook() {
    return this.facebook;
}
}
```

as you can see I have a method to retrieve user notifications but I'm not sure it is working, anyone know how to do this is in a simple manner?

Answer (score 1):

The following code you can use to retrieve the name of the facebook user:

```
public static String getName() {
        String response;
        String name = "";
        try {
            response = ParseFacebookUtils.getFacebook().request("me");
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            name = json.getString("first_name");
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (FacebookError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return name;
    }
```

Comment: You can only call this method after the user has logged in.

Comment: This are the errors I'm getting on the logcat, still no luck..
`07-31 13:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):  at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:215)
07-31 13:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:751)
07-31 13:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:688)
07-31 13:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):  at com.FeedPass.FacebookConnector.getName(FacebookConnector.java:77)
07-31 13:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):  at`

Comment: response = ParseFacebookUtils.getFacebook().request("me");

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the user logging in. Can you read other data from the logged in user?

Answer (score 1):

You can get facebook user name from this

```
String User_name = null; 
try {
    User_name = new JSONObject(facebook.request("username"));

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you retrieve notifications.Even this is an old question. I will post it in case somebody finds it helpful

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
if (state.isOpened()) {
    InboxMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    new Request(session,"/me/notifications", null,HttpMethod.GET,new Request.Callback() {

                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    GraphObject object = response.getGraphObject();
                        if (object != null) {
                            InboxMessage.setText(object.getProperty("data").toString());
                        } else {
                            InboxMessage.setText("Notifications returns null");
                        }
                }
            }
        ).executeAsync();
} else {
    InboxMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
}
}
```